# how to remove table border line?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table. I want to remove table border line, how do I this?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:120px;">Item</th>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Description</th>
            <th style="width:100px;">Unit Cost</th>
            <th style="text-align:right; width:60px;">Qty</th>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Tax</th>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Tax</th>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Line Total</th>

       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>         
     <tr>        
     <td colspan=7 width=800>
     <div id="dataRows">
 <div class="fieldRow" id="template">
    <select class="items" name="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" id="items"> <option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option></select>
     <textarea name="description" id="description" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:211px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 0px 0;"></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" class="unitprice" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 0px 0;">
     <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="quantity" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 0px 0;">
     <select name="firsttax" id="firsttax" class="firsttax" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected" ></option></select>
     <select name="secondtax" id="secondtax" class="secondtax" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:104px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected"></option></select>
     <input type="text" name="linetotal" id="linetotal" class="linetotal" placeholder="0.00" readonly style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:104px; border-radius:0px; background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align:right; margin: -2px 0px 0;">   
    <input type="button"  class="button remove"  id="btnDel" value="Remove Row" style="float:right; margin:0 -110px; color: #ffffff; background-color: #d9534f; border-color: #d43f3a; padding: 3px 10px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.428571429; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;  border:1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;" />
</div>
</div>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <input type="hidden" id="itemscounter" name="itemscounter" value=""/>
     <tr>            
     <td colspan=7 rowspan=2 width=800 style="border:0px solid white;">
     <div style="border:1px solid #DDDDDD; width:317px; height:50px; margin:0 -1px; float:right;">
    <label class="required" id="invoicetotal" for="Invoicetotal" style="padding-top:3px;">Invoice Total(USD)</label>
    <span style=" font-weight:bold; margin:4px -204px 0; float:right;">$</span> 
    <input type="text" class="required" id="invoicetotalamount" name="invoicetotalamount" placeholder="0.00" readonly style=" color:#526273; font-weight:bold; text-align:left; border: 0px solid #000000;"/><br>
    <label class="required" id="paidtodate" for="paidtodate" style="margin-top: -6px;">Paid to date</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" id="paidtodateamount" name="paidtodateamount" placeholder="0.00" style=" color:#526273; font-weight:bold; text-align:right; border: 0px solid #000000;"/>       
    </div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid #DDDDDD; width:317px; height:33px; margin:50px -316px 0; float:right;">
    <label class="required" id="balance" for="balance" style="margin-top:0px;">Balance(USD)</label> 
    <span style=" font-weight:bold; margin:7px 45px 0; float:left;">$</span>    
    <input type="text" class="required" id="balanceamount" name="balanceamount" placeholder="0.00" readonly style=" color:#526273; font-weight:bold; text-align:left; border: 0px solid #000000;"/> 
    </div>   
     </td>       
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

and here is my css:

```
#table{
float: left;
height: 200px;
margin: -291px 19px 0;
width: 825px;
}
```

and here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You should try to use a css file instead of placing the styles with html tags.

Comment: What are the CSS properties set for your `.table-bordered` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<table border="0" style="width:825px;"> </table>
```

put border value 0 in css or declare table border like these above i mentioned.. post ur full css code..

Answer (score 9):

use css

it would be

```
table, th, td
{
  border: 0;
}
table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this code:

```
<table border="0" style="width:825px;border:0px;"> </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple CSS

```
table.myTable { border:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your class  and add/change border to zero or try changing into border tag in table.